# Will nested function be called in mocha unit test after stubbing :AssertionError: expected 'some data' to equal 'stubbed string'

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js, sinon

I am new to unit testing  using mocha and sinon , just to learn more I have stubbed a function to return some string, in my code I call this function as inner function. My test is to see if the stubbed return string is assigned to a variable. Please look at the code snippet to understand more

**file.specjs**

```
let sinon = require("sinon");
let filejs = require('./file.js');
let expect = require ("chai").expect;

it('should run only the outer function' ,function() {

// I try to stub my function here
sinon.stub(filejs,'test1').callsFake ((someArg) => {
  return "stubbed string";
});

// Now I will call my test outer function
   filejs.test();
  expect(filejs.param).to.equal("stubbed string");

})
```

```
    let param;
    module.exports = {
         test,
         test1
    }

    function test () {
      module.exports.param = test1();
    }

    function test1() {
       console.log("should not be called);
       let data = "some data";
       return data; 
    }
```

As I have already stubbed the function test1, I don't expect this to be called, and return from test1 is assigned to param and since we have faked the function to return a different string, I expect this string to be set to param variable.

But when I run the test I see this error

> AssertionError: expected 'some data' to equal 'stubbed string'

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add chai expect to spec file :)

Comment: use `module.exports` not `module.export`

Comment: Thanks  Doug Coburn :) Also I have modified my code snippet, I don't pass any parameter to function test

Comment: I changed my question, I see assertion error now, stubbed function doesn't replace the string value

Comment: I answered too quick. My answer was incorrect.

Comment: It looks like sinon doesn't like stubbing functions from `require()`

Answer (score 1):

Try the following edit...

```js
    function test () {
      module.exports.param = module.exports.test1();
    }
```

For what you are trying to do to have a chance at working.  You need `sinon` to modify the `module.exports` and the code under test needs to read `test1()` from that object.  It may need to be nested deeper in order to modify it... I don't know.  I had troubles using `sinon.stub(require('./something'))`

I think I got it working in a repl.it
https://repl.it/repls/NegativeEnragedMainframe